# Display another arraylist element in textview using onItemSelected of a spinner

Tags: android, arraylist, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I have 2 arraylists, 1 is use to display the elements to the spinner and another one is use to display on a textview when one of the element from spinner is selected.

Example:

0---a---football

1---b---badminton

2---c---basketball

"a,b,c" are the elements in arraylist1; "football, badminton, basketball" are the elements in arraylist2; "0,1,2" are the index for both arraylists.The index of elements on both of the arraylists has already arranged properly as shown above.

What I want to do now is to let the spinner to display "a,b,c". When I select "b" in the spinner, the textview will show me "badminton".

What should I write in the onItemSelected of the spinner?Any idea for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, 
    int position, long id) {
    switch(position){
      case 0: 
      textView1.setText(sportsList.get(0));
      break;
      case 1:
      textView2.setText(sportsList.get(1));
      break;
      case 2: 
      textView3.setText(sportsList.get(2));
       break;
    }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just got an idea from your answer. Since I will add/remove elements from the arraylist, so I don't know what is the size of my arraylist. Besides that, the index of elements in both arraylist are the same,thus I just write "textView.setText(sportList.get(position));".

Comment: @vincentsiau Thats great but i gave you this option so you may set data to the required text view and in case if you wanted to clear the rest you can also set them as `textView1.setText("")` so at one time only one text will be shown on your layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected item in the spinner by this code

`String selected = spinner1.getText().toString();`

Then check for the condition,

`if(selected.equals("a")){
    textview1.setText(array2.get(0));
}else if(selected.equals("b")){
......`

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
    {
      Textview  your_tv = (Textview)findviewbyid(R.id.tv);
      your_tv.setText(your_array[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
    {
    }
});
```